# Database Exporting Gives error in Microsoft SQL server 2014

Tags: sql-server

When I am Exporting Database from Microsoft Sql server 2014 It Gives an Error.  The Error Is in the Picture Below[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IstW.jpg)

Comment: just click on the error link on result.. it will show you the exact problem

Comment: it says "[dbo].[attendace] does not have a clustered index".

Comment: Exporting higher version to lower?